# Training a classifier in Rails and Using it, where to start?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, machine-learning, classification

I'm not sure if this belongs here so please correct me if not. Heres my problem..

I have a rails application that fetches tweets containing a certain hashtag and then (currently) matches the words in the tweet again positive and negative dictionaries to decide if the tweet is 'positive' or 'negative'. These terms are subjective so it would be more accurate if it had a model that I could teach which tweets are good and which are not.

Do I have the right idea here or is there a better solution?

If so how would I go about this and where would I start in implementing it to do this, I mostly understand the concept of teaching a model but not how to implement it.

Comment: Please try using some library, or implementing a classifier on your own, and ask a more precise question. Don't expect the results on Tweets to be very good - garbage in, garbage out; Tweets are mostly garbage.

Comment: I've looked for a library and can't find any, I know it's a really general question but I just don't know where to start and can't find any helpful resources to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Akismet and TypePad AntiSpam integration for Rails.
Complete documentation [here](https://github.com/joshfrench/rakismet)

introduce Rakismet to your model:

```
class Comment
  include Rakismet::Model
end
```

you can even see the [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/65-stopping-spam-with-akismet?view=comments) to configure your application

Comment: I don't understand how this would solve my problem, could you elaborate more?

Comment: you asked for a better solution and so i preferred you to configure your app with Akismet gem. See complete documentation or the railscast  for how to do so. While doing so if you are stucked some where then you can post your difficulty.